# Bot and User Identification, channels Teams and Direct Line

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

I have a bot working on Teams and I'm able to fetch the user's Identity using the `TeamsInfo`. Now I want to get the same bot running on a web site (via direct line) albeit with lesser functionality and a different method of identifying the user.

I'm using `TeamsActivityHandler` as teams specific features (task module, messaging extensions) are being used.

As I want the flow to be different so I understand that I would need separate dialogs. I'm confused on how to approach this with activity handlers? Do I need separate activity handlers or lots of if conditions in one?

PS. I have looked for sample and articles online but didn't find anything about one bot running on multiple channels supporting different features; I can share some code if needed.

Comment: Is your app runs under an API of node.js or it is an independent app for the bots?

Comment: It's running under nodejs using microsoft libraries for bot framework.

Comment: So you want to run chatbot as a channel-specific then first identify the channel through "turnContext.Activity" and it will contain the Channel information, So before processing, you can identify the channel in the bot framework." After that, you can add channel-specific flow.